# dropTarget showing error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm, creating a simple drag and drop game in flash cs 5.5. There will be several movieclip on the stage suffled. What the user need to do is drag it to another movieclip and the movieclip  will switch and check if it is in right place. I used the code something like this

```
 if (evt.target.dropTarget != null && evt.target.dropTarget.parent.name == "num1" || "num2" || "num3" || ......and so on)
{
//do your thing
}
else
{
//go back to original place
}
```

In above code num1, num2 and so on are name of the moveiclips. There are also other movieclips on the stage. They are backgrounds. This works fine if I drag and dropped the movieclip(let say num1) on other movieclips(let say num2) as expected. But when I droped it on other movieclip(background), it shows error. I traced evt.target.dropTarget.parent.name inside the if condition and it shows the name of other movieclip(background). Why it is showing the name of the other movieclip(background) when the condition hasn't met which is the name isn't num1 or num2 or so on...? Can someone tell me if I'm doing anything wrong ? or is there another way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you're posting pseudo-code or not, but this won't work as a condition:

```
evt.target.dropTarget.parent.name == "num1" || "num2" || "num3" ||
```

This will always return true because it's evaluating the string "num2" as a condition.  Look at the [Boolean function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#Boolean%28%29) for more information.

What you want is something like:

```
var par_name = evt.target.dropTarget.parent.name;
if (evt.target.dropTarget != null && par_name == "num1" || par_name=="num2" || par_name=="num3" )
```

or you can streamline this in many ways-- e.g.:

```
var valid_targets = ["num1","num2","num3"];
if ( evt.target.dropTarget != null && (valid_targets.indexOf(par_name)>=0) )
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this simple and dummy example will be possible to explain a little bit more how to implement this logic. (of course, it's just a draft, but can be used as mockup)

Try something like:

```
//your package name (I just created a simple example, you should refactor and add your logic
package nu.gpeart.TheGunnersExample.components
{
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;

/**
 * @file DraggableItem.as
 * @created Dec 18, 2013 - 9:02:52 AM
 */
public class DraggableItem extends Sprite
{
    private var _item:Sprite;
    private var _rightPlace:Point;
    private var _dropTarget:Sprite;
    private var _originalPlace:Point;

    public function DraggableItem(parent:Sprite,
                                  viewport:Rectangle,
                                  color:uint,
                                  rightPlace:Point,
                                  dropTarget:Sprite)
    {
        _originalPlace = new Point(viewport.x, viewport.y);
        _rightPlace = rightPlace;
        _dropTarget = dropTarget;

        _item = new Sprite();
        _item.graphics.beginFill(color);
        _item.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, viewport.width, viewport.height);
        _item.graphics.endFill();
        parent.addChild(_item);

        addMouseDownListener();
    }

    private function addMouseDownListener():void
    {
        _item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        _item.startDrag();
        removeMouseDownListener();
        addMouseUpListeners();
    }

    private function addMouseUpListeners():void
    {
        _item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler, false, 0, true);
        _item.parent.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        _item.stopDrag();
        removeMouseUpListeners();
        addMouseDownListener();

        startLogic();
    }

    private function startLogic():void
    {
        if (_item.hitTestObject(_dropTarget))
        {
            (_item.hitTestPoint(_rightPlace.x, _rightPlace.y)) ? rightPositionLogic() : wrongPositionLogic();
        }
        else
        {
            wrongPositionLogic();
        }
    }

    private function wrongPositionLogic():void
    {
        _item.x = _originalPlace.x;
        _item.y = _originalPlace.y;
        // go back to original place
    }

    private function rightPositionLogic():void
    {
        trace('dropped the right place');
        // do your thing
    }

    private function removeMouseUpListeners():void
    {
        _item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
        _item.parent.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
    }

    private function removeMouseDownListener():void
    {
        _item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    }
}
}
```

And to use, you just need something like:

```
        var rightPlace:Point = new Point(461, 554);
        var originalPosition:Point = new Point(50, 50);
        var itemWidth:Number = 50;
        var itemHeight:Number = 50;
        var viewport:Rectangle = new Rectangle(originalPosition.x, originalPosition.y, itemWidth, itemHeight);
        var itemColor:uint = 0xf67821;

        //container (the Sprite where are you adding all your objects
        //dropTarget (the Sprite you want to detect the hitTest
        var draggableItem:DraggableItem = new DraggableItem(container, viewport, itemColor, rightPlace, dropTarget);
```